# Merge the "retag-request" and the "retagging" tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

On this meta site there are two questions tagged [retag-request](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request), and four questions tagged [retagging](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retagging).
The first should probably be merged with the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These have now been merged and a synonym created.